# c# emgucv conversion of MIplImage type image from BGR color space to HSV color space

Tags: c#, emgucv, data-conversion, hsv, bgr

my task is to convert a program for blob tracking with kinect V1 into a program for blob tracking using Kinect v2.

The first program is written in c++ and uses opencv. The new program must be write in c#, so I'm using the wrapper emgucv.

The first program at a certain point uses this instruction:

```
cvCvtColor(frameVideo,hsvImg,CV_BGR2HSV);
```

frameVideo and hsvImg are defined like this:

```
IplImage* frameVideo=cvCreateImage(cvSize(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT),8,3);

IplImage *hsvImg=cvCreateImage(cvSize(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT),8,3);
```

Now, I'm trying an equivalent way to do the same with C# and emgu.

My equivalent variables are defined like this:

```
MIplImage frameVideo = (MIplImage)Marshal.PtrToStructure(CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(new System.Drawing.Size(Globals.IMAGE_WIDTH, Globals.IMAGE_HEIGHT), IplDepth.IplDepth_8U, 3), typeof(MIplImage));

MIplImage hsvImg = (MIplImage)Marshal.PtrToStructure(CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(new System.Drawing.Size(Globals.IMAGE_WIDTH, Globals.IMAGE_HEIGHT), IplDepth.IplDepth_8U, 3), typeof(MIplImage));
```

Inside emgu there's the equivalent method of cvCvtColor, that is CvInvoke.CvtColor(, ...), whose syntax is the following:

```
public static void CvtColor(
    IInputArray src,
    IOutputArray dst,
    ColorConversion code,
    int dstCn = 0
)
```

Link to documentation of this method: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/80190679-ef98-e1ef-f6b6-4c8b9f3b7f64.htm

So, my problem is that this method requires to work with IInputArray as a source and IOutputArray as destination, but i can't find a way to use my variables (that are of type MIplImage) in that method, or a way to associate frameVideo with IInputArray and hsvImg with IOutputArray.

I've found a way to use the method with the Image type, but in this case I've not find a way to convert from my MIplImage format to Image.

Can anyone help me?

If you have more questions or if you want more details on the code please contact me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the old C code they were creating an image so why not just use a EmguCV Image<> or Mat object. They can always be used where ever a IInputArry or a IOutputArray are used.

Doug